# Show fixed width top bar on horizontal scroll

Tags: html, css, layout

**HTML**

---

```
<div id="headers">
    <header>
        <div id="Logo">
            <img alt="SiteLogo" title="KAS" src="Images/kas.png" />
        </div>
        <div id="LogoText">Sample Site</div>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">HOME</a>

                </li>
                <li><a href="#">ABOUT US</a>

                </li>
                <li class='has-sub '><a href="Products.aspx">PRODUCTS</a>

                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Item 1</a>

                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Item 2</a>

                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Item 3</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">SERVICES</a>

                </li>
                <li id="current"><a href="#">ENQUIRY</a>

                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>
</div>
```

**Fiddle**

---

## [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/PGXc4/1/)

## [Full Page Result](http://jsfiddle.net/PGXc4/1/embedded/result/)

**Issue**

---

As you can see in the **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/PGXc4/1/)** i'm not able to access the all the  menu but if it is in full page like **[Full Page Result](http://jsfiddle.net/PGXc4/1/embedded/result/)** i'am able to access all the menu's

**Needed:**

---

What I need is the following

- Header should be fixed to the top
- i need to scroll horizontally and access all the menus even if i change the width of the browser

Comment: You're sure you want to make the user scroll if the header is too wide? You should probably use responsive CSS for a more friendly experience.

Comment: i need to access other links y scrolling

Comment: try adding overflow:auto; in the headers div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, this isn't possible with pure CSS, because that's how the `position: fixed;` behaves, if you want a jQuery solution, which am aware that you haven't tagged, but you don't have any other way.. *(Or using JS)*

```
$(document).on('scroll', function() {
    $('#headers').css('top', $(this).scrollTop());
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/PGXc4/3/)

Here, I am nudging the `top` property *on scroll* of the document, so your element stays `position: absolute;` but it will behave as if it's `fixed`.

Just make sure that you get rid of `position: fixed;` from `#headers`, you won't need that now, also, `header` background will chop off as it exceeds the viewport so assign some `height` to your `header` element and assign `background-color` as well

```
header {
    width: 1000px;
    height: 80px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    padding: 0px;
    top: 0;
    background-color: #333;
}
```

[**Demo 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/PGXc4/6/)

[**Demo 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/PGXc4/7/embedded/result/) *(Full page, use the inner scroll bar, not the outer one)*

Answer (score 0):

To achieve the result you want you need to add `overflow-x: auto` to your CSS.

```
#headers {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #333;
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    top: 0;
    position: fixed;
    z-index:600;
    overflow-x: auto; /* Added this */
}
```

I've made a demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/PGXc4/2/).  But like others have said you should really look into responsive layouts to make your page more user friendly

Answer (score 0):

I just added overflow scroll to yours and it works for me.

```
overflow:scroll;
```

[fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/PGXc4/8/)