# Different position values for X and Y in CSS3?

Tags: css, css-position

I have a design consisting of a main page next to a sidebar, horizontally centered in the browser window. Since the horizontal position will depend on the client's browser window width I can't use `position:fixed` here for either the main page or the sidebar, I guess.

However, I do want to have a fixed vertical position for the sidebar, i.e. not scrolling with the rest of the page.
So, how can I have at the same time `position:absolute` for the X-position and `position:fixed` for the Y-position?

**To clarify** (some people in comments seem to think it doesn't make sense)
The vertical position in the window should not change, while the horizontal position should change when the browser window gets resized.

Comment: I think you are looking for this http://stackoverflow.com/a/22073879/1542290

Comment: could you provide a live example of your actual layout please.